# Match two columns and put them in one file

Tags: awk

I have two files. In each file I have two columns. I need to match the first value of column two of file1 with each value from column two of file2. If they are equal I need to put the two columns (column one from file1 and file2) in one file, but they should be adjacent to each other. If the two values do not match, do nothing.

file1

```
344  0
465  1
729  2
777  3
676  4
862  5
```

file2

```
766  0
937  1
980  2
837  3
936  5
```

Example output:

```
344    766
465    937
729    980
777    837
862    936
```

Comment: I must be some kind of sucker, this is the second time I formatted a question for you

Comment: With which part are you stuck? If you share your code, we can help you fix it.

Comment: @1_CR: it happens — if you patrol the tags which a particular user is asking questions in, you get to reformat their questions multiple times.  It's most exasperating when the user is still trying to make their own changes to the question, and keep losing your efforts.  You have to respect what they've done, but ... well, it can be annoying.  It's best to wait until they stop editing, then get your changes in.  I frequently save what I've edited using command-A to select all the material and command-C to copy (control-A, control-C on Windows, Linux); and then paste it back in.

Comment: Also, consider using [tag:join]: `join -j2 -o'1.1 2.1' file[12]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist this be done in `awk`

```
awk 'NR == FNR {arr[$2] = $1; next} {if ($2 in arr){print(arr[$2], $1)}}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { values[$2] = $1; next; }
             { if ($2 in values) print values[$2], $1 }' file1 file2
```

While the record number equals the file record number (while reading first file), stash values in column 1 in `values[$2]`, skipping to the next record.  While processing the second file, if there's a value in `values[$2]`, print out the value in `values[$2]` and `$1`.